# Random loss of javascript audio in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I've been developing a browser based game using html5 and canvas objects it's going well so far. However i've run across a strange issue that I believe is related to chrome. Basically, the game can play fine for a period of time (this varies, typically a few minutes) then the audio just stops playing. If you then refresh the page or go on any other page with html5 audio tags then the sounds do not play either. If I take a look at the javascript console's network tab in chrome then i can see the audio objects haven't transferred and have a type and status of 'pending'. I've never got an error like this in firefox, only chrome.

My search online for similar situations only found one link that sound similar http://www.lordofultima.com/en/forum/showthread.php?tid=52813 with users complaining about loss of sound in chrome in this game (which is also done in javascript)

Any pointers? Feel free to ask if you need more info.

Comment: I have the same issue. It's clearly a bug in chrome because, as you said, HTML sounds won't play on *any* page until the browser is restarted. I'd love to know what triggers it or how to avoid it, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove id3 tag of mp3 , it's strange but works , at least i hope

Comment: all the sounds are .ogg though - would this change anything?